# How get code which executes in another thread with ASM?

Tags: java, multithreading, bytecode

I need help. For example I have such class.

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public void runThreads() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int i = 1;
            System.out.println("Thread " + i);
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int i = 2;
            System.out.println("Thread " + i);
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I run classVisitor for `ThreadTest`. And I want to get the byte code which executes in first and second threads. Is there any way to do that? I think I should visit class `Thread` and then visit method `run` in it. But how can I do this from `ThreadTest`?

Comment: Why have you complicated the question by asking how to do it for *two* threads? Why not provide a shorter snippet of code and ask a simpler question?

Comment: I suggest you use the ASMifier view http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html That would show you exactly how to create the code using ASM calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand [how lambdas are compiled](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html). There is no point in analyzing the code of class `java.lang.Thread` as [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) already tells you what it will do, i.e. that it will invoke the `run` method of the provided `Runnable` instance, but that instance will be created at runtime by the `LambdaMetaFactory`.

But your class `ThreadTest` contains the actual code which will finally be invoked. It’s sitting in synthetic methods in this class. When you traverse the `runThreads()` method you will [encounter `invokedynamic` instructions](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitInvokeDynamicInsn(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.objectweb.asm.Handle,%20java.lang.Object...)). The `bsmArgs` parameter depends on the actual bootstrap method of the `invokedynamic` instruction, so you have to look up [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) to understand its meaning. You will learn that it contains a handle pointing to the (synthetic) target method (in your class). So you know that *that method* contains the code that will finally executed by the other thread.

In your case you will encounter two `invokedynamic` instructions pointing to different synthetic methods representing the different code executed by the different threads.